# Providing initialized members to base class constructor

Tags: c++, initialization

Let's say I have flawed C++ code like this:

```
struct A final {
    A(); // Initializes somethingShared

    shared_ptr<Something> somethingShared;
};

struct B {
    B(const A& a);
};

struct C : B {
    C()
    : B(a) {} // Uh-oh

    A a;
};
```

`C` should *be-a* `B`, so it inherits from it. But to initialize a `B`, we need an instance of `A`. `C` has to provide one, but how? In the above code, `a` is used uninitialized, because bases are initialized before members. I need to somehow initialize `A` before `B`.

If `A` *wasn't* `final`, I could inherit privately from `A`:

```
struct C : private A, public B {
    C()
    : B(*this) {}
};
```

But because it's `final`, I do this:

```
namespace detail {
    struct C_Base {
    protected:
        A a;
    };
}

struct C : private detail::C_Base, public B {
    C()
    : B(detail::C_Base::a) {}
};
```

Or I could use weird hacks like this:

```
struct C : B {
    C(const A a = A())
    : B(a),
      a(a) {}

    A a;
};
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could contain `A a` in `struct B` and pass an instance of it to `B`'s constructor like: `B(const A& _a) : a(_a)` from `C`'s constructor: `C(const A& a = A()) : B(a) { }` or `C() : B(A)) { }`

Comment: The best way is to rewrite `C` so that it either doesn't need an `A` data member *or* doesn't need to inherit from `B`. All other solutions, including the one which would be possible if `A` wasn't final, make the code hard to read and understand.

Comment: I cannot change `A` or `B`. `C` needs an `A` member and needs to inherit from `B`. I'm looking for a solution that satisfies the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a private constructor and a pointer:

```
class C : B {
private:
    const std::unique_ptr<A> m_aPtr;
    C(A* a) : B(*a) , m_aPtr(a), m_a(*a){}
public:
    C() : C(new A()) {}

    A& m_a;
};
```

This will ensure that

- `A` is fully constructed before constructing `B`
- `A` is only constructed once and not copied
- `m_aPtr` will stay valid for the lifetime of the class (due to `const`) and will destroy `A` on class destruction properly (like an instanced member)
- You can use `m_a` with the same syntax as an instanced member, because it's a reference. If it's ok for you, you could also leave `m_a` away and work only with the pointer `m_aPtr`.